# reRender doesn't refresh after event

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, rendering

I just have a selectOneRadio and want to display (or not) a panel depending on the boolean  value (basic reRender after an event with a4j).
My binding with the boolean is good, and the action confirms that the boolean value changes on clicking:

Here is my `selectOneRadio` :

```
<h:selectOneRadio  value="#{myController.myBoolean}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{...}"  reRender="myPanel" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="#{true}"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="#{false}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Why is the reRender not working after using the `rendered` attribute (no effect) :

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="myPanel"  rendered="#{myController.myBoolean}">...
```

whereas it works using `style` attribute, by changing the visibility :

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="myPanel"  style="#{myController.myBoolean ? 'visibility:visible;':'display:none;'}">...
```

- Richfaces 3.3.3.Final
- Same bug on every browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be explained as below.
Initially your panel "myPanel" is not rendered because rendered attribute is set to `false`. Then now you change the rendered value to `true` by selecting the `selectOneRadio` component. Then you are going to `reRender` the "myPanel" by using `reRender="myPanel"` in your `a4j:support` tag. 
But unfortunately there is no "myPanel" to be reRendered because there is no such element in your page(because it is not rendered).

You can overcome this issue by reRendering the parent of the "myPanel". For an example if "myPanel" has a parent `panel` as below,

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="parentPanel">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="myPanel"  rendered="#{myController.myBoolean}">
           .......
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Now `reRender` the parent as below

```
<a4j:support event="onclick" action=#{...}"  reRender="parentPanel" />
```

Note: When you change the `visibility` instead of `rendered` attribute, it works because although "myPanel" is hidden it is still available in your page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I suspected that the problem came from there, but I did not manage to bypass. Thanks for the tip !